# What Are Angular Nodes , Radial Nodes, Nodal Plane and Nodal Surfaces?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, orbitals, atomic-structure

Actually, i am confused between all of them. some says that angular node is same as nodal planes and radial nodes is same as nodal surfaces... and what's the difference between nodal planes and nodal surfaces. other says that angular node is the intersection point of nodal plane. please explain in easy explanation.

Comment: Summarize then who says what, and/or focus on single terms. They are rather self-explaining.

Comment: could you please share your explanation on the same

Comment: Write down your understanding effort first.

Comment: what i understood till now is that angular nodes are the intersection point of the nodal plane with the atom..... and radial nodes are the spherical region and the surface which it covers is called as nodal surfance... btw nodes and nodal planes are the areas where e- density  is zero

Comment: actually no, i have read that but couldn't understand

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.

- Nodes are generally 3D surface regions where electron occurrence probability density is zero.
- Nodal planes and surfaces are such nodes from geometrical point of view.
- Radial and angular nodes are such nodes from point of view of wave functions. As either radial either angular part of a wave function is responsible of the zero density value.
- From the geometry of used spherical coordinates, it is quite clear that radial nodes are 3D spherical surfaces with constant radius, like for s orbitals.
- Analogically, a constant angle of angular nodes leads to a 3D plane intersecting the coordinate origin, like for p orbitals.
- Therefore,

  - radial nodes = spherical  nodes
  - angular nodes = planar nodes
- For higher values of n and l quantum numbers, nodes are collection of radial and angular nodes, or nodal spherical surfaces and planes.
- As wave functions do not have sharp boundary, but converge to zero values in infinity, the intersection of an atom and a nodal plane is – mathematically – the nodal plane. Practically the conventional size of atoms.

Comment: could you please differentiate nodal plane and angular node or radial node and nodal surfaces by graphics

Comment: I can, but I will not until you read my answer properly. As it is  there in more than 1 instance.

Comment: sorry i want to say differentiate them by the use of 3D graphics

Comment: Do you need to be provided by 3D graphics to differentiate a plane and a spherical surface? Or to differenciate 2 identical planes or 2 identical spherical surfaces ?

Comment: Have you ever tried the picture section of Google search for *wave function radial angular nodes* ?